# Уникальность SID

Tags: windows

Как известно, у многих объектов в Windows есть такой себе Security Identifier или просто SID.

Вопрос - этот идентификатор глобально уникален или нет? Т.е. могу ли я взять SID локальных пользователей с двух разных компьютеров не входящих в домены и получить пересечения? Или они будут гарантировано уникальны?

Comment: Вообще говоря, не уникален. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier#Duplicated_SIDs